# React admin Post query with param

Tags: reactjs, post, request, react-admin

First of all, i'm new to react & react admin and i'd like to change my post uri from :

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44376/api/pointmesures
Request Method: POST
```

TO

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44376/api/pointmesures&double=true
Request Method: POST
```

I could pass this value in my request Payload but i feel like this is not the right way to do it because this is just a condition for the post request (i might be wrong).

If this is not clear enough ask me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you give us a little more context? Where are you making this POST from? What component are you using?